# Github pages deploy vue project

Tags: vue.js, github, github-pages

I am successfully done deploy to github pages and I have an Active status of deployment. But I can't see my app. And I don't understand what is the promlem:
https://hikkiyarik.github.io/
My repo:
https://github.com/HikkiYarik/HikkiYarik.github.io

Comment: It looks like your JavaScript is not loading. In your html, you have `<script src="/HikkiYarik/js/chunk-vendors.3f1df606.js"></script>`. But the url to the js file is `/js/chunk-vendors.3f1df606.js` and not `/HikkiYarik/js/chunk-vendors.3f1df606.js`. So, replacing it should help. Let me know if that fixes it. (And same thing for the other js file)

Comment: I deleted the project and recreated it. After I did npm run build, the url in the index.html file became as you suggested, but this did not solve the problem. Moreover, I realized that my gh-pages outputs readme, but so far I have not figured out how to get rid of it.

Comment: GitHub pages will turn your markdown files into html, if that is what you mean. To my knowledge, this can't be turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem. We need SSH key for your GitHub account, `deploy.sh` file and two repos like my repos `foodshop` and `HikkiYarik.github.io`.

My GitHub account for example:

```
https://github.com/HikkiYarik
```

Look closely at the contents of the file `deploy.sh`:

```
<git push -f git@github.com:HikkiYarik/HikkiYarik.github.io.git master:gh-pages>
```

This means we push our project that was built in the `foodshop` repo to the `HikkiYarik.github.io` repo.

By the way, `gh-pages` branch is created automatically. Script `deploy.sh` starts running when we write the command:

```
npm run deploy
```

For the command to work, just write a `package.json` file in scripts:

```
"deploy": "sh deploy.sh"
```